# JavaScript JQuery slide effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to make a background slide show effect. What i have managed to do is to make this slideshow but without any beautifully effect like sliding or other image appearing effect. Can someone help with some advice in creating the effect of sliding or any other more beautiful effects.

Here what I managed to do:

HTML CODE

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.1.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="function.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body >
        <div class='bannerbg'>
            <div class='slider'></div>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS CODE

```
body{
    margin: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
}

.bannerbg{
background-size: cover;
position: relative;
height: 500px;

}

.bannerbg img{
    width: 100%;
}

.slider{
    width: 940px;
    height: 360px;
    background-color: #FFDF00;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    top: -370px;
}
```

JavaScript CODE

```
$(document).ready(init)

images=new Array
(
"img/1.jpg",
"img/2.jpg",
"img/3.jpg",
"img/4.jpg"
);  


function init(){
$('.bannerbg').prepend("<img id='principala' src='"+images[1]+"' />")
}

function left() // functia data schimba cu locul indexul din array la stinga cu 1 unitate
    {
        images.push(images.shift());
    }

function change(){
    p=document.querySelector("#principala");
    p.src=images[1];
}

setInterval("left(); change()",1000);
```

Comment: please demo on jsfiddle

Comment: Try to see this: http://jqueryui.com/slider/

Answer (score 0):

I slide the elements by using the **animate** function and by setting the css property and animation time in miliseconds for that element, like that:

```
jQuery( "#slid_img1" ).animate({marginLeft: 0}, 250);
```

It slides very nicely then.
So, you could adapt your code to use the **animate** function to make the slide animate.

Comment: Can you please specify in my code example were do i need to write this line of code of animate. Thank you!